# Stop SpringSecurity from sending an automatic 401 when it can not find an incoming token

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Consider a GET request to a controller which then in turn loads a resource from a database. Imagine the database resource has a flag. The flag sets if the resource is public or not. If the resource flag is true then just return the resource. If the resource is public flag is set to false then check that the incoming user is the correct owner of that resource. If the user is not in that case send a 401.

How can I configure spring security to account for this use case?

Comment: In general, use `@PostAuthorize`, which is not in common use but is intended for this case.

Comment: @chrylis why is it not common?

Comment: Because most of the time, you know ahead of time whether to permit the call, and it is more efficient to return the error _before_ doing anything. Note that if it's cheap to retrieve the database object (e.g., just a SQL or MongoDB call), it may be easier from a development perspective to let Spring Data's `DomainClassConverter` fill in the MVC parameter and just use `@PreAuthorize` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned, you could use `@PostAuthorize`.

For example, assuming you have a service method that returns a `DatabaseResource` that has a `publicFlag` and `owner` fields, the following will throw an `AccessDeniedException` if `publicFlag == false` and `owner != authentication.name`.

```
@PostAuthorize("returnObject.publicFlag == true 
                 || returnObject.owner == authentication.name")
public DatabaseResource returnResource() {
    // load the resource...
    return databaseResource;
}
```

Comment: is the `returnResource()` the method that would have the `@get` annotation on it?

Comment: It's recommended to have method-level security on service methods

Comment: Note that you're accessing fields on the built-in returnObject name in the expression. Using this on a controller will most likely complicate things. Is your controller returning ResponseEntity?

Comment: Yes. In the case where the resource is not public  I will access our "currentUser" service which pulls some stuff out of the security context and gives me back a DTO of the signed in user. In the case of the public flag being true I would never need to touch the security context. That logic I'm fine handing in the controller method.

Comment: Ok how about putting this logic in an authorization bean with a method, say hasPermission(), that you can then invoke after the controller method has retrieved the resource.

Comment: Something like @PostAuthorize("@authBean.checkPermission(returnObject,authentication)")
on your controller method.

Comment: Just make sure the method returns a boolean.

Comment: Whether to put security annotations on controllers or on underlying services is a design decision that can legitimately go either way; in particular, different controllers may have different authentication regimes (session vs. OAuth) that require different assertions.

Comment: @Stewart `ResponseEntity` is never a *wrong* return, but unless you're setting custom headers on the response, it's nearly always simpler to return the object immediately (you can throw an exception to indicate an error).